How to run window invisibly and prevent interaction with rest of desktop, but with GPU acceleration?
I want to run some GUI applications invisibly, and prevent interaction with the rest of the desktop (e.g. avoid them stealing focus), but with GPU acceleration, so they run performantly.
This is in order to automate some tasks using a PyAutoGUI script without preventing me from using the PC while the script is running. For convenience, I don't want to have to run this process on a separate PC.
Options I've considered, and their issues:

wmctrl -i -r WINDOW_ID -b toggle,below, to keep the window below the others

Doesn't allow me to interact with the window using PyAutoGUI, as the window isn't in focus.
Window may still be able to grab focus somehow.
May be detectable by applications.


Xephyr (or similar tools like Xvfb)

No GPU acceleration.
Doesn't run in a normal xorg session/desktop environment, so it acts differently
May be detectable by applications.


Virtual machine

High overhead.
GPU passthrough probably not possible on my hardware configuration.
May be detectable by applications.



So far, Xephyr seems the best to me, but it lacks GPU acceleration. Are there any workarounds for the issues I've had with above options, or any alternative methods?
